# How to safely check for a attribute value with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a clicked link has target="_blank" set as an attribute, I want to call window.open, otherwise I set a iframe to load the page.

How do I check the attr and make sure it doesn't crash if the value is null etc.

I have this so far:

```
if ($(that).attr("target") == "_blank") {
       window.open(linkHref, "_blank");
}
else {
       document.getElementById(someFrame).src = linkHref;
}
```

I am scared that if `$(that).attr("target")` is not set, or is empty, it will crash.

Comment: 1. Why don't you test this case that you're "scared" of? 2. It won't.

Comment: Why are you scared that it will crash? Has it in the past?

Comment: If will work fine just try.. However there is no need in block with `window.open`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From JQuery documentation:

> Access a property on the first matched element. This method makes it
>   easy to retrieve a property value from the first matched element. If
>   the element does not have an attribute with such a name, undefined is
>   returned. Attributes include title, alt, src, href, width, style, etc.

It will not blow up, but return undefined instead if the attribute is missing.  So expect the potential of an undefined to be returned, and adjust accordingly.

Worse comes to worse, you can always wrap volatile code in try/catch to circumvent an error.

Comment: so $(that).attr("target") == "_blank" will crash then right? I can't tell b/c it happens fast and I can't see it in chrome's console.

Comment: @user1361315 How do you define the word "crash"? If `$(that)` doesn't have a "target" attribute, its value will be `undefined`. When you compare `undefined` to `"_blank"`, its result is `false`. There should be no crashing.

Comment: @Ian is correct, it won't crash.  It will evaluate to false on the equality check.